# $.when().done() is firing the done function before when completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, .when

I have a page like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.when(ajaxcall1(),ajaxcall2(),ajaxcall3()).done(finalCall());
});
```

For some reason the `finalCall()` is firing simultaneous to the three calls surrounded by `$.when()`.

I tried calling a reference to the `finalCall()` function as in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.when(ajaxcall1(),ajaxcall2(),ajaxcall3()).done(finalCall);
});
```

But even then, it still fires the function before the prior 3 complete.

**NOTE:** I am not including the functions here as they are not relevant. I just need to know why the `finalCall()` function would fire simultaneous to then `$.when()` functions.

Thank you.

Comment: *"I am not including the functions here as they are not relevant."* except.... they probably are relevant if changing from `finalCall()` to `finalCall` doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.when` does not call your callback at all. You are doing it yourself:

```
//                                                        vv
$.when(ajaxcall1(),ajaxcall2(),ajaxcall3()).done(finalCall());
//                                                        ^^
```

Change that to

```
$.when(ajaxcall1(),ajaxcall2(),ajaxcall3()).then(finalCall);
```

where the *function* is actually passed into the promise method, and it'll work (assuming your ajax functions return promises).